# var vs const; why const is producing error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'userOne' has already been declared?

Tags: javascript, class, scope, var

When vars are replaced with const the code is producing an error. I run this code in the chrome browser console. I tried initializing the variable with let but that is producing an error as well. I ve checked docs on variables before asking this question and I know I am missing something crucial here.

```
class User {
    constructor(email, name){
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = 0;
    }
    login(){
        console.log(this.email, 'just logged in');
        return this;
    }
    logout(){
        console.log(this.email, 'just logged out');
        return this;
    }
    updateScore(){
        this.score++;
        console.log(this.email, 'score is now', this.score);
        return this;
    }
}

class Admin extends User {
    deleteUser(user){
        users = users.filter(u => {
            return u.email != user.email
        });
    }
}

//const userOne = new User ('ryu@ninjas.com', 'Ryu');
var userOne = new User('ryu@ninjas.com', 'Ryu');
var userTwo = new User('yoshi@mariokorp.com', 'Yoshi');
var admin = new Admin('shaun@ninjas.com', 'Shaun');

var users = [userOne, userTwo, admin];
//const users = [userOne, userTwo, admin];

admin.deleteUser(userTwo);


console.log(users);
```

Comment: You said you're running this in the console? You will get an error like this if you ran it with `var` first and then tried running it again with `const` directly after, as the `var` definition you created in the earlier run will conflict ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m41t1.png)). You'll need to refresh your page first and then run the `const` version. Also making `users` const won't work because you're reassigning it in your `deleteUser` method.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, it works now. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

That happen Because you have two variables `userOne` with the same name.

With `let` and `const` you can't declare more than one variable with the same name in the same scope, but with `var` it will not reproduce an error.

Also, because you are re-assing the const value of users, declare it with `let` not `const`

```js
class User {
  constructor(email, name){
      this.email = email;
      this.name = name;
      this.score = 0;
  }
  login(){
      console.log(this.email, 'just logged in');
      return this;
  }
  logout(){
      console.log(this.email, 'just logged out');
      return this;
  }
  updateScore(){
      this.score++;
      console.log(this.email, 'score is now', this.score);
      return this;
  }
}

class Admin extends User {
  deleteUser(user){
      users = users.filter(u => {
          return u.email != user.email
      });
  }
}

const userOne = new User('ryu@ninjas.com', 'Ryu');
const userTwo = new User('yoshi@mariokorp.com', 'Yoshi');
const admin = new Admin('shaun@ninjas.com', 'Shaun');

let users = [userOne, userTwo, admin];

admin.deleteUser(userTwo);

console.log(users)
```

Comment: when I try const the other variable with var is commented so at a given time I only have one variable userOne

Comment: Yes, Also that happen because you re-assing the `const` value of `users`, declare it with `let` not `const`, I update the answer with working code, please check.

Comment: Thanks but your updated code produces the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'userOne' has already been declared. I run it int the Chrome console

Comment: You are welcome, But It's working fine, please run the code snippet I provided, it will not produce any error and the `userTwo` will be removed from `users` array.

Comment: Thanks, the fault was with me running it in the console and not refreshing the console after every run as suggested above by Nick Parsons. Apprecite your help though, I wonder where did you check this code, in the console?

Comment: You are welcome, No, I run it in StackOverflow code snippet.

Comment: You can use Fiddle for a live editor to test your code. https://jsfiddle.net/